# $R=k[x_1,x_2,...]$ is the ring of polynomials in countable many variables, and $A=(x_1,x_2,...)$. Why is $A^{-1}=R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

This is a step in (among other ways) a way of showing $A$ is non-invertible. Note that $A\subsetneq R$. Assume $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}=\{f\in Frac(R): fA\subseteq R\}$. It can be shown that $A^{-1}=R$, so that $AA^{-1}=A\subsetneq R$, a contradiction.

I don't know how to show $A^{-1}\subseteq R$. I have for $1/h \in A^{-1}$, $x_i/h =g\in R$, and by irreducibility of $x_i$, $h$ is a unit. But how to show $h$ is unit for an arbitrary element $g/h \in A^{-1}$?

Comment: You don't want $1/h\in A^{-1}$, but $f/h\in A^{-1}$, $f,h\in R$.

Comment: Hint: only finitely many $x_i$ can appear in the expansion of the denominator $h$.